# Help Identifying what derailleur hanger I can use

Tags: derailleur-hanger

I bought this frame and have no idea what type of derailleur was on it.  I have the back wheel and it has 8 gears. I feel this is a legitimate question and none of the other similar questions answered my question.  Please don't close this question I really need help with this.  Is there one I can use that is held on by the axle?  The question that was identified as a duplicate did not show which type of hanger or where I could buy one.

[image]

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

There is [this type](https://www.ramcycleparts.com.au/derailleur-hanger-adaptor-for-semi-horizontal-drop) of adapter, which requires a screw to hold it in position. The screw in the adapter should be attached to a cam nut that syncs into the end of the dropout.

Comment: Any 8 speed derailleur should work with this type of adapter. I haven't looked for any links to similar questions, But you question seems legitimate to me, and if it wasn't answered well enough there should be no harm in the asking. I hope my answer was helpful.

Comment: Yeah, that is probably what was on the bike.

Comment: while any 8 speed derailleur will mount it needs to be compatible with the shifters you plan on using. Generally sShimano shifters with Shimano derailleurs, Sram and Sram

Comment: Of course it's wise to check compatibility first, but there is some compatibility between brands.